# How to delete specific line in Text elements using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, mxd, text

I work with several maps (in folder named "aa") and the text boxes in the layout view are:

[image]

I try to delete,using Arcpy, the empty line in the this text properties box

[image]

so my result will be one line only:

[image]

By the way, i have also an empty line in this text box:

[image]

this is my python code:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = r"G:\desktop\Project\aa"
for mxdname in arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd"):
    print mxdname
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"G:\desktop\Project\aa\\" + mxdname)
    for elm in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT"):
        elm.text = elm.text.replace(' ', 'free zn space')
    print 'done'
    mxd.save()   
del mxd
```

but there no changes in the maps and i get this result:

```
>>> 
landUse.mxd
done
1
>>>
```

Comment: The is a extra backslash in your `mxd` variable. And what if you add a print statement within the `for` loop?

Answer (score 1):

What is the name of the text element?

The script you have written does not identify what element needs changing.

I would insert this line to find out what the element names are:

```
for elm in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT"):
    print elm.name
```

Then I would use that to identify which element needs the changing, and then use:

```
for elm in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT"):
    if elm.name == inset_element_name:
        elm.text == elm.text.strip.lstrip()
```

Please see [python text formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) to find out more on how to remove the blank spaces.